# map insert: class as key and class as value

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have two class StorageAddress and PersistentChunk. I define a map called SsdChunkMap.

```
typedef std::map<StorageAddress, PersistentChunk> SsdChunkMap;
SsdChunkMap* _SsdChunkMap;
```

I want to insert data to map.

```
StorageAddress _StorageAddress(victim._addr);
PersistentChunk _PersistentChunk(victim._hdr.pos.offs, victim._data,
            victim._hdr.compressedSize);
    _SsdChunkMap->insert(make_pair(_StorageAddress, _PersistentChunk));
```

And I overload the operator <

```
  inline bool operator < (StorageAddress const& other) const
    {
        if(attId != other.attId)
        {
            return attId < other.attId;
        }
        if (coords.size() != other.coords.size())
        {
            return coords.size() < other.coords.size();
        }
        for (size_t i = 0, n = coords.size(); i < n; i++)
        {
            if (coords[i] != other.coords[i])
            {
                return coords[i] < other.coords[i];
            }
        }
        if (arrId != other.arrId)
        {
            //note: reverse ordering to keep most-recent versions at the front of the map
            return arrId > other.arrId;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

_SsdChunkMap->insert(make_pair(_StorageAddress, _PersistentChunk));

So, this is right?

Comment: Define "right".  Syntactically correct?  Produces the correct output?  It looks "right" to me, but I can't say unless I know what you are looking for.

Comment: You can probably simplify the `operator<`, either with `coords < other.coords` (all std:: container's have an operator<) or `std::lexicographic_compare(begin(coords), end(coords), begin(other.coords), end(other.coords))` (which is what std::vector <  does)

Comment: In fact, `return std::tie(attId, coords, other.arrId) < std::tie(other.attId, other.coords, arrId)` does it in one expression